# How to skip blank lines in my .txt file while running a program in python

Tags: python-3.x, text-files, blank-line

I am coding a program that reads and extracts data from a text file and then does some calculations with the data.

However, due to the empty spaces in my textfiles, there was an error in retrieving numbers. I get

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base10: ' '

My text file looks like that:

```
['flower', 'sdfsd', '21/08/2019 20:27:03', 1]

['hello', 'sdsdfsdf', '21/08/2019 20:27:36', '2']

['car', 'sdfsd', '21/08/2019 20:27:45', 1]

['table', 'sdfsdf', '21/08/2019 20:29:21', 1]

_(blank space \n)_

['shirt', 'sdfsdf', '21/08/2019 20:30:02', '2']

_(blank space \n)_

['hello', 'sdfsdf', '21/08/2019 20:30:07', '3']
```

and my code to write into the text file from python looks like that:

```py
historyFile = open('history.txt','a')
historyFile.write("\n\r")
historyFile.write(file)
historyFile.close()
```

I have already tried examples online like `if not line.strip():` but it stopped retrieving data after the blank line

The following are my codes:

```py
readFile = open('history.txt','r')
searching = readFile.readlines()
i=0
for line in searching:
    if i in range(len(searching)-1):
        i += 1
        oldCount = str(int(searching[i].split(",")[3][-4]))
        newCount = str(int(searching[i].split(",")[3][-4]) + 1)
        print("\nold count: " + oldCount + " new count: " + newCount)
```

It is supposed to run through all the lines in my text file and return the numbers in my list at position 3 but due to the empty lines, I am getting the error

[image: my output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `history.txt` contains (note the blank lines):

```
flower, 'sdfsd', '21/08/2019 20:27:03', 1
hello, 'sdsdfsdf', '21/08/2019 20:27:36', 2
car, 'sdfsd', '21/08/2019 20:27:45', 1
table, 'sdfsdf', '21/08/2019 20:29:21', 1

shirt, 'sdfsdf', '21/08/2019 20:30:02', 2

hello, 'sdfsdf', '21/08/2019 20:30:07', 3
```

Then this script will read the file and print the last column increased by 1:

```
with open('history.txt', 'r') as readFile:
    for i, line in enumerate(readFile, 1):
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue

        line_tuple = tuple(map(str.strip, line.split(',')))

        oldCount = int(line_tuple[3])
        newCount = oldCount + 1
        print("row no. {} old count: {} new count: {}".format(i, oldCount, newCount))
```

Prints:

```
row no. 1 old count: 1 new count: 2
row no. 2 old count: 2 new count: 3
row no. 3 old count: 1 new count: 2
row no. 4 old count: 1 new count: 2
row no. 6 old count: 2 new count: 3
row no. 8 old count: 3 new count: 4
```

---

Edit: If your `history.txt` contains quoted fields:

```
'flower','sdfsd','21/08/2019 20:27:03','1'
'hello','sdsdfsdf','21/08/2019 20:27:36','2'
'car','sdfsd','21/08/2019 20:27:45','1'
'table','sdfsdf','21/08/2019 20:29:21','1'

'shirt','sdfsdf','21/08/2019 20:30:02','2'

'hello','sdfsdf','21/08/2019 20:30:07','3'
```

You can use `csv` module to read it:

```
import csv

with open('history.txt', 'r') as readFile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(readFile, delimiter=',', quotechar="'")

    for i, line in enumerate(csvreader, 1):
        if not line:
            continue

        oldCount = int(line[3])
        newCount = oldCount + 1
        print("row no. {} old count: {} new count: {}".format(i, oldCount, newCount))
```

Comment: if the user enters a word in the input 'flower' and i want to add a count to that word, how do i find that exact row that has the word 'flower'?

Comment: @finanzaf You can have `if` statement, like `if 'flower' in line[0]: ...`

Comment: but what if i dont know the row number? i am thinking of using a loop to find [i]. how do i write it?

Comment: @finanzaf `line[0]` is first column. In variable `i` you have line number. so if `'flower' in line[0] == True`, you know the row number. It's in variable `i`.

Comment: so, line[i][3] will give me the count of the word i typed?

Comment: @finanzaf No, `i` is line number, variable `line` holds tuple of values of current line. For example `line[0]='flower'`, `line[1]='sdfsd'` `line[2]='21/08/2019 20:27:03'` and `line[3]=1`. I would suggest to put some debug print statements into the code to see what each variable holds.

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in searching:
    if line != '\n': # check if line not '\n'
        if i in range(len(searching)-1):
                  ....
```